# Scala macros. How to instantiate subclass and dynamically mixin trait

Tags: scala, macros, traits, scala-quasiquotes, scalajs-react

## Motivation:

*(not tightly associated with this topic but states a use case. Skippable)*

I'm using `Scala.js` to write [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) code. I now have a `form` which contains bunch of `input`s, each needs a `onChange callback` in its props. See [Controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

```
case class Input(info:String,value:String,onChange:(e:Event)=>Unit)
```

The problem is: `info` which has nothing to do with `React`, but has been coupled with it. I would split control logic apart from web contents. So I did:

```
trait Control[T]{val value:T,val onChange:(e:Event)=>Unit}
case class Input(info:String)

//when need to create a controlled props:
private trait TextInputCtrl extends Control[String]{//..implementation}
new Input("some info") with TextInputCtrl
```

This only solved half the coupling problem. Because implementation of `TextInputCtrl` has to be written inside React component to access state. So does `new Input(...)`, unless make `TextInputCtrl` public. But if you do, you carry React logic outside.

Well. **If trait could be dynamically mixed into instance**. I could create an uncontrolled clean `Input` instance somewhere else, and pass it into React component. Much more flexible. This even provides leverage like:

```
Seq(input...).map(_ with XXControl)
```

So, I did some trying:

## The question:

I wanted to use this simple philosophy:

```
def dynamix(in:Input):Input with Control{
  new Input(in.info) with Control{//..implementation}
}
```

but via macros:

```
 q"""
   new $MixinToolSym[$tpeC,$tpeT]{
       def dynamix(in: $tpeC): $tpeC with $tpeT = {
          new $tpeC (..$constrBody) with $tpeT
       }
   }
 """
```

I reached successful compilation. But failed at runtime:

```
trait MixinTool[C, T] {
  def dynamix(in: C): C with T
}

object MixinTool {
  implicit def materialize[C, T]: MixinTool[C, T] = macro MacroImpl.impl[C, T]
}


val mt=MixinTool.materialize[Input,Control]
mt.dynamix(inputInstance) //error
```

It throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: 
tried to access field x.x.Input.info from class x.x.X$$anon$3$$anon$2
```

**What's the problem?**

This is not a problem about `scala App`.

===================================================

### Discussion about other ways to reach decoupling goal:

Other approaches:
(**but probably not the best solutions**)

Below both lose self type traits' ability to directly access other fields. And hard to incrementally chain or partially override control logic.

```
case class PropsContainer(input:Input,control:Control = Control.empty)
```

or:

```
case class Input(info:String,value:String="",onChange: Control = Control.empty)
def addControl(input:Input,control:Control):Input{
  input.copy(onChange = control)
}
```